# OSX One-step converting from ZIP to DMG via terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, zip, dmg, converters

Is there an elegant way of converting ZIP files to DMG?
I would avoid to expand the (many) files manually and then to repack'em to a DMG.
Could that be done via terminal, maybe in a single step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an app called [DropDMG](https://c-command.com/dropdmg/) that lets you convert between file types. The description on the website claims you go from .zip to a dmg file. The app is not free but they have a free trail available that may work for you.

A terminal command that might work is hdiutil.

```
hdiutil create -format UDZO -srcfolder folder_to_compress archive_name.dmg
```

I just tried this on a .zip file and it worked. But note that when I launch the .dmg file I just get the .zip file back.

You could also write a two line script.  First line is to unzip the zip file and then use the hdiutil command to make a dmg from the expanded files.

Comment: jupp, the creation of a DMG via terminal works fine.
will check the App

Comment: PS.: the App does it absolutely easy, drop a ZIP, get a DMG.